# Detect youtube video restriction

Tags: youtube-api

I've noticed that lot of youtube videos on my portal show this message:

"This video contains content from XXX, who has blocked it from display on this website"

For example:
http://www.karaoketexty.cz/texty-pisni/hurts/silver-lining-162276

Is there any way how to detect these videos via youtube API?
There is no relevant info about it on http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&q=dA1xykDtzbo

I'm using Zend_Gdata_YouTube and getVideoEntry method. I can successfully detect removed videos, embed disabled and country restriction.

But I don't know how to detect this new type of blocking (for specific website).

Thank you for any suggestions or tips.